# Getting a wrong output

Tags: c++, algorithm

### The problem

There are N toys and their weights is represented by an array W = {w<sub>1</sub>, w<sub>2</sub>, …, w<sub>N</sub>}.

Each toy costs 1 unit and if a toy with weight w<sub>i</sub> is bought, then we can get *all* other toys whose weight lies within [w<sub>i</sub>, wi + 4] (both inclusive) free of cost.

### Example:

```
W = {1, 2, 3, 17, 10}
```

If the 1st toy with weight 1 is bought for 1 unit, then the 2nd and 3rd toy become *free* since their weights lies within [1, 5]. The last two toys have to be bought separately.

### My Code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    if(a[i + 1] - a[i] <= 4) {
        ans += 1;
    }
}

ans = n - ans;
cout << ans;
```

I am getting the wrong answer. What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: any chance you could explain what your code is doing? Also, what output you're getting?

Comment: That is not a problem statement. It's a description of a situation in which a problem may be formulated. For example, an actual problem statement would be "Find an algorithm to maximize the number of toys bought under a budget constraint of K units of money". But i just made that one up.

Comment: What output are you expecting? The number of items left when buying an item with specified index? I mean, you have described a problem but *not* what you're supposed to solve.

Comment: [Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w12/challenges/priyanka-and-toys)

Comment: @user4206991 You can *not* access that page without signing up.

Comment: i could not pass all the testcases for the above example the output should be 3

Comment: @user4206991 Ok, but why should it be 3? What does the number 3 represent? An *ammount* or and *index* or whatnot? It's like saying the answer is 42 (but what is the question?). No one can say if your code is correct or wrong if it's not clear what its *supposed* to do.

Comment: What answer does your current code give?

Answer (score 0):

[This would be a comment but I don't have enough reputation]

It's hard to answer this question because it isn't clear what output you're expecting. However, it looks like you're original array `a` needs to be sorted for this approach to work, but from the example you give that isn't necessarily the case.

Having said that I might have misinterpreted exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You gave an example in which you get the second and third toy for free, so you checked both `W[bought_toy + 1]` and `W[bought_toy + 2]`.

However, in your code you only check `W[bought_toy + 1]`, so you would never know that you also get the third toy for free.